# How to prevent your class from being inherited in c++?

Tags: c++

How to prevent your class from being inherited in c++?

Comment: In c++ 11 you can use the `final` keyword like: `class myClass final { };`

Comment: Mark it as  `final`

Answer (score 5):

> How to prevent your class from being inherited in c++?

Mark it as [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final).

```
class MyData final {
  // ...
};
```